# Multi variable Limit question

Tags: limits

Could it be shown graphically that the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^3y^3)}x+y^2 \ ?$$

exists? Based on some graphs it appears that any path picked would go to zero

Comment: @Creative: Your function is undefined on the $y$-axis.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг: Why do you say the function is undefined on the curve $x = -y^2\,$?

Comment: For small arguments, the sine can be approximated by the argument and the function tends to $x^2y^3+y^2$. More formally, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^2y^3\sin(x^3y^3)/x^3y^3=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^2y^3\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\sin t/t$.

Comment: Question has been edited. My apologies.

Comment: @quasi I am unable to spot the question, it is not appearing in my received comments box. Can you help me find it?

Comment: @quasi: but $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x^3y^3)/x=0$ for all $y$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Agreed, the limit, as you approach the point (0,y), from within the domain, is y^2, proved algebraically (as you showed).

Answer (score 0):

Though a plot proves nothing, the function looks very smooth at the origin. (Indeed, it is perfectly approximated by a fifth degree polynomial and the limit is indisputably $0$.)

[image]

Comment: So can I use a graph to look for paths to take where limit likely to not exist ?  It seems that with enough

Comment: The above picture shows all possible paths. What more do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Since $| \sin \alpha | \leq |\alpha|$ for any angle $\alpha$, you can take $\alpha = x^3 y^3$ and conclude that
$$
|\sin (x^3 y^3) | \leq |x|^3 |y|^3.
$$
As a consequence,
$$
\left| \frac{\sin (x^3 y^3)}{x} \right| \leq x^2 |y|^3,
$$
so that the left-hand side converges to zero as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. The term $y^2$ is harmless, and goes to zero trivially.

Comment: Is this graphical ?

Comment: Ok thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, I cannot plot 3D graphs, my faith does not allow that to solve limits.